# Mi vector de objetos se sobreescribe

Tags: java, array, objeto, serialización, vectores

Muy buenas, estoy creando un pequeño proyecto de serializacion de clases, mi problema radica en  que al momento de ingresar un nuevo objeto a mi vector este se sobreescribe. Cuando le doy a generar reporte solo se me genera el ultimo objeto que guardo en vehiculos alguien me podia indicar en donde se encuentra el problema o que debo cambiar en mi codigo...?

Gracias de antemano !!!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthOptionPaneUI;
import Archivos.Escritura;
import Archivos.Lectura;
import Entidades.Propietario;
import Entidades.Vehiculo;

public class Principal {
    public static int n = 0;
    
    
    public static int contador = 0;
    public static Vehiculo[] vehiculo = new Vehiculo[n];
    public static Vehiculo[] vehiculo2 = new Vehiculo[100]; 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombreArchivo = "Vehiculos.dat";
        Escritura<Vehiculo> salida = new Escritura<>(nombreArchivo);
        Lectura<Vehiculo> entrada = new Lectura<>(nombreArchivo);
        
        
        
        String ced = "", nom = "", vin1 = "", marca1 = "", modelo1 = "";
        int capacidad1 = 0, anio1 = 0;
        double valor1 = 0;
        
        
        
        boolean validar = false;
        
        
        
        // ----------------------------------MENU-----------------------
        
        
        
        String si = "";
        String n1 = "";
        
        
        
        do {
            System.out.println("----------MENU----------\n1. Ingreso de Vehículo\n2. Reporte de Vehiculo\n3. Salir");
            
             n1 = scan.next();

            if (n1.matches("[1-3]*")) {
                menu1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
                validar = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("---------------ERROR---------------\nPor favor ingresa un número válido\n");
            }
    
        int i=0 ;

        
        
        switch (menu1) {
            
        case 1:
            do {
                
                System.out.println("Cuantos vehiculos desea ingresar?");
            
                 n1 = scan.next();
                
                
                
                if (n1.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                    n = Integer.parseInt(n1);
                    
                     vehiculo = new Vehiculo[n]; 
                    
                    validar = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("---------------ERROR---------------\nPor favor ingresa un número válido\n");
                }

            } while (validar == false );

        
            
            for ( i =  contador; i < vehiculo.length; i++) {
                
                
                
                boolean validacion = false;
                
                
                System.out.println("Registre el vehículo " + (i + 1));

                System.out.println("\nRegistre el propietario");

                // ----------------------------------CEDULA-----------------------
                do {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese la cedula");
                    String cedula = scan.next();
                    if (cedula.length() == 10 && cedula.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                        ced = cedula;
                        validacion = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("--------------ERROR---------------\n"
                                + "Por favor, ingrese los datos correctamente!!\n");
                    }

                } while (validacion == false);

                
                
                // ---------------------------------- NOMBRE -----------------------
                do {
                    validacion = false;
                    System.out.println("Ingrese su Nombre");
                    String nombre = scan.next();
                    if (nombre.matches("[A-Z, a-z]*")) {
                        nom = nombre;
                        validacion = true;

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("---------------ERROR---------------\nPor favor, solo letras\n");
                    }

                } while (validacion == false);

                
                
                
                // ---------------------------------- VIN -----------------------
                System.out.println("\nRegistre el vehiculo"); // 1GNCS13Z6M0246591
                do {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el Vin");
                    String vin = scan.next();
                    validacion = false;
                    if (vin.length() == 17 && vin.substring(0, 1).matches("[0-9]*")
                            && vin.substring(1, 5).matches("[A-Z]*") && vin.substring(5, 7).matches("[0-9]*")
                            && vin.substring(7, 8).matches("[A-Z]*") && vin.substring(8, 9).matches("[0-9]*")
                            && vin.substring(9, 10).matches("[A-Z]*") && vin.substring(10, 17).matches("[0-9]*")) {
                        vin1 = vin;
                        validacion = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(
                                "---------------ERROR---------------\nPor favor, ingrese correctamente los datos\n");
                    }
                } while (validacion == false);

                
                
                // ---------------------------------- MARCA -----------------------
                do {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese la marca");
                    String marca = scan.next();
                    validacion = false;
                    if (marca.matches("[A-Z, a-z]*")) {
                        marca1 = marca;
                        validacion = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("---------------ERROR---------------\nPor favor, ingrese solo letras\n");
                    }
                } while (validacion == false);
                
                
                
                

                // --------------------------------------- MODELOS -------------------
                do {
                    validacion = false;
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el modelo");
                    String modelo = scan.next();
                    if (modelo.matches("[A-Z, a-z]*") || modelo.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                        modelo1 = modelo;
                        validacion = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(
                                "---------------ERROR---------------\nPor favor, ingrese correctamente los datos\n");
                    }
                } while (validacion == false); //
                
                
                
                
                // ----------------------------------------- CAPACIDAD -----------------
                do {
                    validacion = false;
                    System.out.println("Ingrese la capacidad");
                    String capacidad = scan.next();
                    if (capacidad.matches("[0-9]*") && Integer.parseInt(capacidad) > 0
                            && Integer.parseInt(capacidad) <= 10) {
                        capacidad1 = Integer.parseInt(capacidad);
                        validacion = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("---------------ERROR---------------\nPor favor ingrese un número válido\n");
                    }
                } while (validacion == false);

                
                
                
                // ----------------------------------------VALOR----------------------------
                do {
                    validacion = false;
                    // 999 999 999
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor");
                    String valor = scan.next();
                    if (valor.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
 
                        if (valor.length() <= 10 && valor.length() > 0) {
                            valor1 = Double.parseDouble(valor);
                            validacion = true;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("--------------ERROR-------------\nEl número ingresado es muy grande\n");
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println(
                                "---------------ERROR---------------\nPor favor ingrese un valor numérico válido\n");
                    }

                } while (validacion == false);
                
                
                
                // ----------------------------------------ANIO-----------------------------
                do {
                    validacion = false;
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el año");
                    String anio = scan.next();
                    if (anio.matches("[0-9]*") && Integer.parseInt(anio) > 1700 && Integer.parseInt(anio) <=2023) {
                        anio1 = Integer.parseInt(anio);
                        validacion = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("--------------ERROR----------------\nPor favor, ingrese un año válido\n");
                    }
                } while (validacion == false);
                
                
                        
                try {
                    
                    vehiculo[contador] = new Vehiculo(new Propietario(ced, nom), vin1, marca1, modelo1, capacidad1, valor1, anio1);
                    salida.abrir();
                    salida.escribir(vehiculo[contador]);
                    salida.cerrar();
                    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    
System.out.println("No Guardado");              
    
                }
                
                
                
                
                
                
            }
        
            break;

        case 2:
            
            System.out.println("Reporte de vehiculos");

            try {
                entrada.abrir();
                
            do {
                    vehiculo2[i]= entrada.leer();
                    if(vehiculo2[i] != null)
                        System.out.println(vehiculo2[i]);
                } while(vehiculo2[i ] != null);
            
                entrada.cerrar();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No hay ningun vehiculo registrado");    
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("No hay ningun vehiculo registrado");    
        


        }
            
            
            
            break;
            
        case 3:
            System.out.println("----------GRACIAS POR SU VISITA----------");
            System.exit(0);
            
            
            
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Desea vovler al menu? S/N");
         si = scan.next();
        
        } while (validar = false ||  si.equals("S"));
        
        
        
    }
    
    static boolean val1 = false;
    static int menu1=0;
    
    
    

    
    

}
```

Muy buenas, estoy creando un pequeño proyecto de serializacion de clases, mi problema radica en  que al momento de ingresar un nuevo objeto a mi vector este se sobreescribe. Cuando le doy a generar reporte solo se me genera el ultimo objeto que guardo en vehiculos alguien me podia indicar en donde se encuentra el problema o que debo cambiar en mi codigo...?

Comment: muy probablemente estes guardando siempre el mismo objeto, en lugar de un objeto nuevo.. pero ese codigo, no lo mostraste...

Comment: Hola Josue, recien cuando tengas creados todos los vehículos, debes guardarlos, porque así como lo haces, sobre-escribes el archivo.

Answer (score 0):

revisando un poco lo que escribiste el problema, al menos para mi, seguro que está acá.

```
vehiculo[contador] = new Vehiculo(new Propietario(ced, nom), vin1, marca1, modelo1, capacidad1, valor1, anio1);
salida.abrir();
salida.escribir(vehiculo[contador]);
salida.cerrar();
```

Estás utilizando la variable **contador** para acceder a la posicion del Array. Se lo asignás a la variable **i** cuando inicias el for(). Pero nunca lo incrementas despues de cada iteracion. Es un error comun igual, la correccion debería ser así:

```
vehiculo[i] = new Vehiculo(new Propietario(ced, nom), vin1, marca1, modelo1, capacidad1, valor1, anio1);
salida.abrir();
salida.escribir(vehiculo[i]);
salida.cerrar();
```

Capaz ya lo solucionaste, pero si no es asi, espero que te sea de ayuda!